„Zu Beginn" vs “am Beginn" vs „beim Beginn“?
Was sind die Unterschiede zwischen

zu Beginn


am Beginn


beim Beginn

?
Ich glaube, dass die Erste die Häufigste ist, aber ich habe auch die anderen Varianten gesehen.

Da gibt es keinen Unterschied. Siehe hier:
https://www.dwds.de/wb/Beginn?o=beginn
Wenn du die Wortkombinationen beispielsweise bei Google eingibst, erhältst du so viele Treffer:

"zu Beginn": 92.800.000
"am Beginn": 3.870.000
"beim Beginn": 384.000

Ich muss aber dazu sagen, dass ich "beim Beginn" selbst nicht kenne und vermutlich nie gehört habe. Mir ist "bei Beginn" (1.690.000 Treffer bei Google) geläufiger.
Auf die Anzahl der Treffer bezogen hast du auf jeden Fall recht: "zu Beginn" ist die häufigste Variante (bei Google).

Die erste Variante ist richtig, die anderen falsch.
Am Beginn ist wohl eine Verwechslung mit am Anfang.
Beim Beginn bräuchte ein Substantiv, wenn da schon ein Artikel ist (das m). Die Substantivierung von beginnen, um den Aktioncharakter zu erhalten, lautet aber das Beginnen. Korrekt wäre also: Beim Beginnen des ...

Was genau ist an "am Beginn" falsch, das an "am Abend", "am Montag", "am Ende" oder "am Anfang" richtig wäre? Nebenbei: "bei dem" kann sowohl maskulin als auch neutral sein: "Beim Sterben ist jeder der Erste"

Nicht alles was hinkt ist ein Vergleich. Generell sollte man in der Linguistik sehr vorsichtig sein mit Vergleichen. Weil etwas irgendwo funktioniert, kann man nicht analog sagen, es tut es anderswo genauso.
Weder am Abend noch am Ende bezeichnen einen Anfangspunkt. Beide bezeichnen ein Während.
Am Anfang bezeichnet tatsächlich den Anfangspunkt, nur wird diese Formulierung eben nicht verwendet, man sagt "zu Anfang". (Kann es sein, daß ich gerade mit einem NIchtmuttersprachler konversiere?)

Was die Erklärung darüber, daß beim sowohl für ein Dativ maskulin als auch neutrum stehen kann, mit dem hier disktutierten zu tun hat, erschließt sich mir nicht. Zumal ich ja ein Neutrum benutzte (das Beginnen) und mir dann auch mit einem Neutrum (das Sterben) exemplifiziert wird, daß es auch für ein Maskulinum funktionieren würde.

Erstens ist "der Beginn" (d.h. ein Maskulinum) nicht die Substantivierung des Verbs "beginnen", und zwar nicht nur, weil der Infinitiv  bereits ein Substantiv ist und als solches keiner weiteren "Substantivierung" bedarf, sondern auch, weil "der Beginn" und "das Beginnen" zwei verschiedene Worte sind. Die (implizierte) Frage nach meiner Muttersprache weise ich als ungehörig zurück und sie wird auch nicht beantwortet. Jedenfalls ist das Austauschen von (Text-)Nachrichten keine "Konversation" und deshalb "konversieren" wir auch nicht.

Wenn "beim Beginn" ein "Substantiv brauchen [würde], wenn da schon ein Artikel ist (das m)", dann frage ich micht - ganz nichtmuttersprachlich - jedenfalls, ob "der Beginn" kein Substantiv ist, sodaß noch eins gebraucht werden sollte. Das war der Grund, warum ich angeführt habe, daß "beim" (also "bei dem") sich sowohl auf maskuline ("der Beginn") wie neutrale ("das Sterben") Substantive beziehen könnte.
